# How to restore Unicode UTF-8 UTF-8_unicode_ci Mysql dump file?

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0, mysql-workbench, c#-3.0

I restore Mysql dump file (character Set:- UTF-8, collation: UTF-8_unicode_ci) into database by:
In Mysql Command Line i  typed this code;
`create database Test_db;
use Test_db;
source C:\Dbn.sql;`

information is not readable:

This is the restored table of dump file:

[image: this is the restored table of dump file]

And the original Database should look like this:

[image: and the original Database should look like this]

Comment: Sure it isn't a problem of `order by`? Try adding an `order by` to both queries. And I don't see how C# could enter in a system problem of a db. Ah... And try opening the `Dbn.sql` with notepad++ and take a look at it.

Comment: Sir Actually its Font problem.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I doubt someone could deduce from your brief question that this is a font problem. Can you add, by way of editing the question, the information that leads you believe it is a font issue? Why is it not an encoding problem?

Comment: MySQL Query Browser has reached EOL since years already and is not secure nor maintained. Instead use [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). This product also can better cope with international characters.